# Login prompt remains after deleting user

Tags: debian, user-accounts

I delete a user using `deluser`. I can't find any file related to it on the system, no entry in `/etc/passwd`, but on login screen it still remains, prompting for login. Why so?

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the `deluser` command ?

Assuming GDM is your login manager, you can maybe see this answer : https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/100824/115683

Comment: Yeah! The solution is there! Thanks'. Worked for me.

Comment: You're welcome ! If your problem is solved btw, flag it as answered :-)